# AngularJS - directive unit test nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying a SIMPLE directive Unit Test but it is not working. I am getting: `Error: Unexpected request: GET my-directive.html
No more request expected`

Not sure what that means, it works in the web page...

**LIVE DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/SrtwW21qcfUAM7mEj4A5?p=preview

**directiveSpec.js**:

```
describe('Directive: myDirective', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myDirectiveModule'));

  var element;
  var scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<my-directive something="thing"></my-directive>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.thing = {name: 'My thing'};
    scope.$digest();
  }));

   it('should update the rendered text when scope changes', function() {
    scope.thing.name = 'My new thing';
    scope.$digest();
    var h1 = element.find('h1');
    expect(h1.text()).toBe('My new thing');
  });
});
```

**app.js**:

```
angular.module('myDirectiveModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.doSomething = doSomething;

        function doSomething() {
          vm.something.name = 'Do something';
        }
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        something: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-directive.html'
    };
  })
  .controller('DirCtrl', ['$scope', function() {
    this.getName = 'Hello world!';
  }]);
```

How do I simply test a directive unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the template request. Because the directive has the `templateUrl` it try to make a get request, but the $http doesn't expect any request so it fails.
You can mock the request with a response of yours or put the template into the template cache service.

```
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('my-directive.html','<h1 ng-click="vm.doSomething()">{{vm.something.name}}</h1>');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<my-directive something="thing"></my-directive>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.thing = {name: 'My thing'};
    scope.$digest();
  }));
```

Also on your `it` function call `$apply` and use `$evalAsync`.
[See my forked plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/q5l7kNZxn6B2ba57ItQi?p=preview)

Comment: But how do I get whatever `<my-directive></my-directive>` compiles?

Comment: Using the `$compile` service and then calling the `$digest` method

Comment: Didn't I do that in line 5 and line 7 of the code you posted?

Comment: Yes you did. But you asked ;-). The problem with the request is describe in the answer

Comment: Got it. Thank you. And by `response of yours`, you mean insert any data for the directive to work with/

Comment: When you mock a request usually you provide some kind of data (fixture) the are hard-coded for this response. look at the $httpBackend documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend